# Discover file references with wrong casing, because of case-sensitive file system

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core

I am developing an application on .net core on my windows machine.
The app is running on a docker container with the microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 image.

Everything seems fine on my computer, even when it is running in the docker container. The problem appears when it is deployed, where it is running on the same image, but on a linux instance.

for example a reference with wrong casing doesnt work.

reference: ´../Components/Car´;
actual filename: car

This will work on Windows, but not on linux.

This is because the linux file system is case-sensitive while the windows is not.
This happens for backend and frontend apps. Is there a way to circumvent this issue or find the issue earlier in the development cycle? Is there a frontend and/or backend developer tool for this stuff?

Comment: An easy method would be to develop on Linux.

Comment: I don't think you can. Use a CI/CD pipeline to find any issues like this sooner.

Comment: To develop on linux would be the best option, but we have a lot of old .NET applications which doesn't run on linux. Until they are upgraded that is not an option.

Comment: To find this issue in the CI/CD pipeline would be perfect, but how?